# Setting date or string of date to calendar in java

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am having the code this way...

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar currentcal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.set(2012, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 28);

    currentcal.set(currentcal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            currentcal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            currentcal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    if (cal.before(currentcal))
        System.out.print("before");
    else if (cal.after(currentcal))
        System.out.print("after");
    else
        System.out.print("Equal");
}
```

My need is i have to set the date like "2012-09-27" or 2012-09-27 to **cal.set(2012, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 28);**

instead of setting date as **cal.set(2012, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 28);**

To be clear dynamically means, i want to set directly the date from database like "2012-09-27" or 2012-09-27 to calendar directly.

i need **cal.set("2012-09-27");**
or
i need **cal.set(2012-09-27);**

instead this way...

**cal.set(2012, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 28);**

Comment: Why do you want to get answers?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [DateFormat.parse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) ?

You can construct a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with the appropriate format you wish to parse, and the result of parsing the input string is a `java.util.Date`.

(note that if you're getting the date from a database, then it's likely to come back as a [java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) and you won't have to parse it at all)

Comment: yes you are correct i am getting date from db as java.sql.Timestamp.I will retrive only 2012-09-27 from that timestamp.My need is i have to set this date to cal object as cal.set(2012-09-27); instead of cal.set(2012, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 28);